# Interpreting Average Marginal Effect in raw numbers

Tags: regression, logistic, causality, treatment-effect, marginal-effect

I fitted a logistic regression model with a binary exposure variable *X*, trying to understand the effect it has on a given outcome *Y*, which measures infection (yes/no). I calculated the odds ratio of the variable of interest as well as the Average Marginal Effect, both highly significant. Particularly, in my case the AME associated with *X*=1 is -0.0245 [-0.0201;-0.0283]. This means that the probability that *Y*=1 (infection occurs) are reduced by 2.45% when *X*=1.

Now, how do I move from this to a simpler explanation regarding the raw count difference between the two groups (i.e., treated and control)? Something like:

*"given that in my dataset I have 2,000 observations, with 1100 treated and 900 untreated, the AME is telling us that the probability that Y occurs is 2.45% lower for treated, translating to a reduction of **Z**  infected patients"*

What do I have to use? The baseline unconditional probability of infection? I am a little bit confused about the process. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are there covariates in the model or is the only predictor the exposure?

Comment: In this case I do not have covariates, the exposure is the only predictor. I also have a model with some controls, but the AME is basically the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have one categorical explanatory variable, then your logit model just replicates a cross tabulation. So if you want to report effects in terms of raw counts, then the easiest way to do so is just report the cross tabulation.

Comment: Thanks Maarten. And at that point I would compare the difference in raw counts between infected (Y=1) with (X=1) and without (X=0) treatment? What if instead I add controls to the model?